# Did any group in Turkey oppose Cyprus invasion?

Tags: turkey

Did any group in Turkey oppose Cyprus invasion?

If **Yes**,

- Were they political groups or non-political/human-rights groups?
- What was their rationale or objective?
- Were they arrested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [Revolutionary Workers' and Peasants' Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutionary_Workers%27_and_Peasants%27_Party_of_Turkey) (1969-1977) and its leader [Doğu Perinçek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do%C4%9Fu_Perin%C3%A7ek) opposed the military operation in Cyprus.

Doğu Perinçek wrote the book *Cyprus Issue* (Turkish: Kıbrıs Meselesi) in 1976. In this book, he explicitly states that this operation was an occupation.

> And military intervention and occupation, in any case, and whoever
>   does it, will carry an imperialist and reactionary character. (page 24)
>
> The continuation of the Turkish occupation also causes the Greek
>   soldiers to remain in the island, and the necessary conditions for new
>   massacres and killings are being experienced. (page 31)

He also calls [Rauf Denktaş](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rauf_Denkta%C5%9F) (1st President of Northern Cyprus) fascist.

> Turkey should also put an end to support the fascist Denktaş in
>   Cyprus. (page 76)

Here is the cover of that book:

[image: kibris meselesi]

Doğu Perinçek's biography on Wikipedia doesn't mention any arrest relevant to Cyprus. By the way, he is still an active politician and the leader of the [Patriotic Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriotic_Party_(Turkey)).